# Muse Min Height Won't Adjust

Tags: muse

I am in Muse and have a big area at the bottom of my website that I can not adjust to make it smaller.  I go into my page > page properties and change the min height to 500 but it will adjust back to 1467.  I know there are blue arrows with lines connecting them that you can drag to adjust but they won't move up any more! I am going crazy! Please help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

May be You have a no-visible element (like empty text box or a form widget) that doesn`t let the page adjust the min height. Try unblocking all content and then select the gray area on the bottom to see if there is something on it. Hope this is still useful.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and was able to solve it by disabling the master attached to the page. This removed all the whitespace that resisted going away no matter what settings I set in the page properties.
After the issue was resolved I simply re-applied the master to the page and everything was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is open up your Master Page for the individual page that you are referring to, and change the footer of the Master Page by moving it higher up.  Your footer should not begin too low down your page so that it is lower than the footers of individual pages (i.e. Master page content needs to be shorter than individual pages page content).  Muse is set-up so that if your footer is set too high on the Master, it can be adjusted and moved lower on a corresponding individual page.  However, the reverse is not so; i.e. if your footer is too low on your Master, then corresponding individual pages will have the same footer beginning mark, and you cannot adjust it on your individual pages to make it higher on your page.  Thus you will have blank space between your page content and your footer, and your page will automatically re-adjust to sync with the corresponding Master Page.

Answer (score 1):

Try unchecking Sticky Footer in the dialog box Page Properties for [name of page].
Control Bar > Page > Page Properties...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a Master page. I noticed I had a menu widget (3rd party) that had a placement size (not the actual menu size but the size of the widget's outline when placed on the page) that extended below where I wanted the bottom of page and footer. I just resized the widget's placement size and was then able to adjust the blue arrows back up to where I wanted them. The menu widget looks fine when viewing page.